# Undefined reference to extern variables

Tags: c++, extern, qt4.8, qxmpp

I'm using qxmpp library while extending it. I've faced problem when I using `extern char*` variable from that library. There is a `QXmppConstants.h` that contains `namespaces`. I've included qxmpp library it works fine. But when I compiled my project in windows it prompts the following error:

`error: undefined reference to ns_bytestreams'`

`error: undefined reference to ns_disco_info'`

`error: undefined reference to ns_disco_items'`

How to fix that?

Comment: A library is not only the header files, it's also the actual *library* that you need to *link* with.

Comment: I've linked it in my *.pro file.

Comment: Are you statically linking against qxmpp.lib? Or are you using qxmpp.dll? Then you need to export your new symbols from that DLL.

Comment: I linked the following: include(W:/qxmpp-0.7.6/qxmpp.pri) // source
              INCLUDEPATH += $$QXMPP_INCLUDEPATH LIBS += -LW:/qxmpp/src $$QXMPP_LIBS // compiled one